# Replace a line of text to multiple files in directory using Bash or Perl

Tags: linux, bash, perl, file

I have a directory with approximately 9000 files, all of them have the same structure, like the following:

```
      seqfile = brown.nuc * sequence data file name 
      outfile = mlb * main result file 
     treefile = brown.trees * tree structure file name 
        noisy = 3   * 0,1,2,3: how much rubbish on the screen 
      verbose = 0   * 1: detailed output, 0: concise output 
      runmode = 0   * 0: user tree;  1: semi-
automatic;  2: automatic 
                    * 3: StepwiseAddition; (4,5):PerturbationNNI
```

I would like to replace the line "seqfile = brown.nuc" with a word contained in a list in a txt file, the list is like this and

```
organism_1.fna 
organism_2.fna 
organism_3.fna 
organism_4.fna 
organism_5.fna
```

The output  that I'm trying to get will be

```
seqfile = organism_1.fna * sequence data file name 
  outfile = mlb * main result file 
 treefile = brown.trees * tree structure file name 
    noisy = 3   * 0,1,2,3: how much rubbish on the screen 
  verbose = 0   * 1: detailed output, 0: concise output 
  runmode = 0   * 0: user tree;  1: semi-

 seqfile = organism_2.fna * sequence data file name 
      outfile = mlb * main result file 
     treefile = brown.trees * tree structure file name 
        noisy = 3   * 0,1,2,3: how much rubbish on the screen 
      verbose = 0   * 1: detailed output, 0: concise output 
      runmode = 0   * 0: user tree;  1: semi-



seqfile = organism_2.fna * sequence data file name 
      outfile = mlb * main result file 
     treefile = brown.trees * tree structure file name 
        noisy = 3   * 0,1,2,3: how much rubbish on the screen 
      verbose = 0   * 1: detailed output, 0: concise output 
      runmode = 0   * 0: user tree;  1: semi-
```

I've been trying with Sed and Awk but I can't get the output.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: If you can post your Sed or Awk attempts Erick, that'd be great - even if they don't work, that would give the question much more direction, and would help readers help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```sh
for file in *.ext; do 
    for replacement in $(<replacements.file) ; do 
        sed "s/brown\.nuc/$replacement/" < "$file"; 
    done > "$file.processed"; 
done
```

This will put changed data in `$originalFilename.processed`, which you can copy over original files later on if you need to.

Comment: The inner loop will iterate over all the replacements for each file.

Comment: Yes, that's what the OP is after as far as I understand. So that was intentional.

Comment: Ah, you're right, it's possible to read the question in this way.

Comment: [Dont read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: None of those is a problem given the data samples we've got. And it does seem to be a one time task, where robustness doesn't matter. For a reusable script you'd be totally right, though.